# Why do we need int *ptr = NULL;?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, declaration

I don't quite understand why in this example we need a part `int *ptr = NULL;`. I understand what pointers are, but why do we need this * (points at a value attached to an address) here? And why do we need NULL here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[5] = {22, 33, 44, 55, 66};
    int *ptr = NULL;
    int i;

    ptr = a;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(ptr + i));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are not sure about which variable's address to assign to a pointer variable while declaration, it is recommended to assign a NULL value to your pointer variable. A pointer which is assigned a NULL value is called a NULL pointer.
In your case it is not necessary because you assign address `&a[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

This intermediate initialization

```
int *ptr = NULL;
```

is redundant. You could write at once

```
int *ptr = a;
```

Moreover such an initialization is a bad programming style. Each variable should be declared and initialized where it is used. Otherwise the code will confuses users as it confused you.

I would rewrite the program the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 22, 33, 44, 55, 66 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( const int *ptr = a; ptr != a + N; ++ptr ) 
    {
        printf( "%d ", *ptr );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

There are cases when the same one pointer can be used in various contexts. In this case it makes sense to declare it and initialize with NULL. But your simple program is not the case.

Comment: How is it possible, that it is admissible to change the value of a constant pointer `const int *ptr = a` during the loop and why you do it constant? I did not know that this is possible. And one thing to say for the OP, that he can´t use this pointer than anywhere else in the program, if he want to, but you also pointed that a little already. This is very cool code by the way.

Comment: @RobertS It is not the pointer itself that is constant. It is the data pointed to by the pointer that is constant. Using the qualifier const  means that within the loop the pointed data will not be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the first explanation first. But isn´t that unnecessary to make the array constant? I´ve run your code on Online GDB without the `const` qualifier there. It is printing out the same result. Why do you make it constant? I don´t see any source which is causing a change in the array´s own data. What is the benefit of it?

Comment: @RobertS The qualifier const says the readers of the code that within the loop the pointed data will not be changed. So this loop can be used for example when the array is also const.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `int *ptr = NULL` is completely redundant as you could just write `int *ptr = a` as Vlad has already said, but more generally it is a good idea to initialise pointers to `NULL` because if for some reason you have an error in your code and you need to debug it, it is a lot easier to debug what is happening to the pointer if it starts as `NULL` than if you hadn't initialised it and it is filled with some garbage value.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't quite understand why in this example we need a part `int *ptr = NULL;`.

[...]

> why do we need this * (points at a value attached to an address) here?

You are mistaking the significance of the `*`.  In that context, it is not the unary `*` operator.  Rather, it is part of the syntax for declaring a variable whose type is a pointer type.  The declaration declares `ptr` as a variable of type `int *`, *i.e.* pointer-to-integer.  Without the `*`, the declaration would be designating `ptr`'s type as `int`, not as a pointer type.

> And why do we need NULL here?

You don't.  The `= NULL` is an *initializer* for variable `ptr`, defining its initial value, but you assign a different value to that variable before ever reading it, so the initializer has no practical significance.

Some people are inclined to provide such initializers as a matter of course, on the theory that it avoids accidental usage of wild pointers and / or allows (otherwise-)uninitialized pointers to be detected, but as Emerson wrote, "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds."  The initializer serves no useful purpose in this particular code.  If one insists on providing an initializer then there's no reason not to initialize `ptr` directly to `a`:

```
int *ptr = a;
```

as your other answers also suggest.